# Dispose different stream inside returning stream function

Tags: c#, wpf, cryptography

I have function which return CryptoStream:

```
public static CryptoStream CreateStream(string inputfile, string password)
    {
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] salt = new byte[32];

        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputfile, FileMode.Open);
        fsCrypt.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);

        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
        AES.KeySize = 256;
        AES.BlockSize = 128;
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 50000);
        AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
        AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
        AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

        return new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    }
```

And i call it like this:

```
CryptoStream cs = FileCryptoDecryptor.CreateStream("file.xml.aes", AppPass);
```

In CreateStream function im creating filestream and my question is when i call `cs.Dipose();` does it dispose filestream too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 4th optional parameter to the constructor of `CryptoStream`, at the moment it is being disposed by default. You can pass `true` as an extra parameter to leave it open.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStream__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Security_Cryptography_ICryptoTransform_System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStreamMode_System_Boolean_

Comment: Happy to help, feel free to give it the green check

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with @Stuart approach, for interfaces which doesn't provide disposable functionality I use wrapper:

```
public sealed class DisposableStream : Stream
{
    public override bool CanRead => _inner.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek => _inner.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite => _inner.CanWrite;

    public override long Length => _inner.Length;

    public override long Position { get => _inner.Position; set => _inner.Position = value; }
    private readonly IDisposable _disposable;
    private readonly Stream _inner;

    public DisposableStream(Stream inner, IDisposable disposable)
    {
        if (disposable == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(disposable));
        _disposable = disposable;
        _inner = inner;
    }
    public override void Flush()
    {
        _inner.Flush();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return _inner.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        _inner.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _inner.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        _inner.Close();
        base.Close();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {            
        _inner.Dispose();
        _disposable.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Then if I want to wrap everything in return function:

```
public Stream OpenComplexRead(string path)
{
    var a = new FileStream(path);
    var b = new DisposableStream(new CryptoSomethingStream(a), a);
    var c = new DisposableStream(new TracingStream(b), b);
    return c;
}
```

This will aggregate everything in one place;